# XML 'name' attribute, and XML variable type with SelectNodes

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have two questions regarding XML...

1. Given an XML node like this

   ```
   <Product name="Dave">
   ```

   and assigned to a variable with `SelectSingleNode`, `$xmlNode.name` will return Dave. However, if the XML is

   ```
   <Product id="Dave">
   ```

   Then `$xmlNode.name` will return Product.

   Since "name' can refer to either an attribute of the node, or the name of the node itself, does this argue against using Name as an attribute at all, and best practice is to use something like ID as here? Or is this just not really likely to be an issue, m and if name makes more sense then run with it?
2. Given a bunch of Product nodes, and code like this

   ```
   $tempProducts = $temp.xml.SelectNodes('//Product')
   ```

   `Write-Host "$($tempProducts.GetType())"` will suggest that the type of the resulting variable is

   > System.Xml.XPathNodeList, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0,
   >   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

   And yet, `[System.Xml.XPathNodeList]$tempProducts = $temp.xml.SelectNodes('//Product')` will throw an error,

   > Unable to find type [System.Xml.XPathNodeList].

This comes up as I have been typing my variables in a large script with the thinking that it might save me some debug time. But this one condition seems to be giving me trouble.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you use XPath to select your attributes, then you can consistently use `.Name` for attribute name retrieval and `.Value` for the text values of those attributes. If you are using `SelectNodes()`, it will output a `XmlNodeList` type. Why cast it to something else?

Comment: With regards to the type, I wasn't trying to cast, I just wanted to intentional type the variable with what I would get. So I used getType() to determine what I needed to use. Seems GetType is... wrong here?

Comment: I guess I don't have a definitive answer for you. `$temp.xml.SelectNodes('//Product') -is [System.Xml.XmlNodeList]` still returns true since that is its base type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re 1:

PowerShell *adapts* XML elements for convenience, by surfacing both their child nodes and their attributes as regular *object properties*.

This generally makes working with XML in PowerShell very convenient, but has its pitfalls:

If there's a naming conflict with the properties of the underlying [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement) type, the *adapted* properties take precedence.

This happened with the `Name` *attribute* in your sample XML: PowerShell exposes it as a `.Name` *property*, which *shadows* the `XMlElement`'s `.Name` property that reports the *tag name*.

A simple workaround is to call the property accessor *method*, `.get_Name()` to get the shadowed `XmlElement` property:

```
$node = ([xml] '<xml><Product Name="Dave" /></xml>').SelectSingleNode('//Product')

$node.Name       # adapted property: Name *attribute* -> 'Dave'
$node.get_Name() # native property: tag name -> 'Product'
```

That said, if you control the format of the XML, it is preferable to *avoid* such conflicts to begin with.

---

Re 2:

[`.SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes#System_Xml_XmlNode_SelectNodes_System_String_) perhaps surprisingly returns a type that is *derived* from the documented [`System.Xml.XmlNodeList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist) return type and that derived type is itself *not public*: [`System.Xml.XPathNodeList` is `internal`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XPathNodeList.cs,14).

That is not a problem in practice, given that what matters is that it can act as a `System.Xml.XmlNodeList` instance, but can be confusing.

Given an instance of a type, you can inspect the type's derivation (chain of base classes) as follows:

```
$nodeList = ([xml] '<xml><Product Name="Dave" /><Product Name="Jane" /></xml>').SelectNodes('//Product')

$type = $nodeList.GetType()
do {
 $type.FullName 
} while ($type = $type.BaseType)
```

The above yields:

```
System.Xml.XPathNodeList
System.Xml.XmlNodeList
System.Object
```